# как расположить flex-блоки по середине на определённом промежутке?

Tags: html, scss

Нужно расположить 3 flex-блока по середине на определённом промежутке.

Я ставил `justify-content: space-evenly`, но расстояние слишком большое, нужно меньше.

Как установить между блоками 95 пикселей?

[image: 3 блока]

```
&__r {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-top: 67px;
    
       
}
```

вот ссылка на git hub, где всё лежит(src/sass/blocks/_advantages.scss, с 13 строки) https://github.com/fickus-3/pulse

Answer (score 0):

```
&__t {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto ;
    justify-content: center;
}
&__r {
    margin: 67px 95px 0 0;
    &:nth-child(3) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```